# How to make a barplot from a data frame that was imported (without manually inserting the data)

Tags: r, bar-chart

How do I make a barplot for this data frame that I have imported:

[image: Downloaded data]

I would like it to have all of the states on the x-axis, where each state is comparing the three variables (ATSI, non-indigenous, not stated) in three different colours (I don't really need to include total), then the numbers on the y axis. 
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We will help with programming problems, but you are first expected to have a go yourself, which your question does not show. The question is likely to be deleted as off topic or unclear. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information

Comment: You are asked to first search for an answer. There are many answered questions about manipulating wide data (which is what you currently have) to long data which is what formula methods for plotting generally expect. You are also asked not to provide "pictures of data" but instead present examples that can be used for coding demonstrations. (downvotes and close votes not mine)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only giving a picture of the data, I'll make up my own:

```
> df = data.frame( VIC = c(10,8,6), QLD = c(11,5,8))
> rownames(df) = c("Aboriginal", "non-indigenous", "na")
> df
               VIC QLD
Aboriginal      10  11
non-indigenous   8   5
na               6   8
```

Here's how I created a barplot with legend:

```
colours = c("red", "blue", "white")
barplot(as.matrix(df), beside = TRUE, col = colours)
legend("topright", rownames(df), cex=1.3, bty="n", fill=colours)
```

It gives me this:

[image: barplot]

Note that I learned the `barplot` syntax from here:  http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/

Comment: thanks, but I was wondering if there is any way to not have to do:
`> df = data.frame( VIC = c(10,8,6), QLD = c(11,5,8))` 
Do you have to do it manually each time? Or can you use the fact that it is a data frame already... what if it was a big set of data?

Comment: If you already have a dataframe, and it's called `df`, then you should be able to run my last three lines of code to create your barplot.